Swagger UI link on group of endpoints
I am grouping my endpoints with tags. It works great. But, I would like to have links on different groups, like this:
https://host.com/api/v1.0/swagger/{TagName}


Do you mean permalinks to individual tags/operations within Swagger UI? Or do you want a separate Swagger UI page per tag?

Yes, deepLinking is exactly what I am looking for. Thank you.

Helen provided the answer: deep linking.
Example for .Net Core:
app.UseSwaggerUI(options =>
{
    options.EnableDeepLinking();
});

